# How do I make WebStorm format html properly inside @component [template] in Angualar 2?

Tags: html, angular, formatting, webstorm

this is what I'm looking for:

[image: Correct formatting]

this is what I'm getting:

[image: Incorrect formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline templates auto-formatting is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-18307](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18307) for updates